# What window managers remember window position?

Tags: window-placement

What, if any WMs do remember window position (location, size, etc.)?

(I know this is an opinionated topic so I'm only asking what WMs, not why or why not to do it :) )

If it matters, I'm running 16.04.

Comment: I can conclusively say that sometimes, Xfce does. It will remember, for instance, where Skype was last time I had it open, but the splash screen will appear wherever it wants to (usually in the middle of the "active" monitor. I'm pretty sure Gnome3 and KDE behave this way, too. It also depends on what GUI framework is used. I believe GTK applications do this, but Qt do not. That could be a rumour I'm starting though.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Ubuntu distro's with KDE environment and in KDE one can set positions for almost every window (type, class, name). Really miss this in normal Ubuntu (Unity).

Comment: I have found something similar for Ubuntu, I use CompizConfig Settings Manager for this kind of functions in Ubuntu 16.04. Although it is not perfect, one can configure a lot more than standard in Ubuntu. (sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager) At least you can tell a window on what screen it has to open and if it has to open fullscreen or not.